# What component should i use instead of listbox?

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, listbox

My app shows newsfeed from social network. Every feed has different attachments - images, video, audio, etc, - so every feed has different height. Newsfeed shows in listbox using template selector. I read [MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2010/10/06/silverlight-for-windows-phone-7-listbox-scroll-performance.aspx) and as i can see - i broked almost all rules how to use listbox (non fixed sized items, nested listboxes, and so on). As result - i have laggin listbox, which jumping from item to item when it wants. So, if MS couldn't make a listbox, which can normaly works with dynamic items, what sould i use to get smooth scrolling by items?

UPD: Why minuses? Can you explain? Its a bad question? I think not only for me its important.

Comment: nice try, Sergey Brin :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the ItemPresenter control with a ItemTemplate.

Comment: thanks, I'll try. I just founded the exaple in Charles Petzold's book

Answer (score 1):

You could try stackpanel inside a scrollviewer.

Also you could make images and text load only when scrollviewer gets close to displaying that item, not load everything all the way at the start.
This reduces internet traffic, loading time and the lag while scrolling. Ofcourse it will take some of your coding time, but believe me - it will be well worth it! Most services use this thus cutting server load and traffic.

Check if that helps!

Comment: Thanks! Can you show some example, how to make delayed download?

Comment: You have to implement the delayed loading logic by yourself. Easiest way i see is custom usercontrol, where phisical loading process of the image to image control is controled code-behind, but im sure other users more advanced could offer a solution with an easier approach!